# How to set FlexLayout height automatically according to its children height

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to create a FlexLayout without specifying its height as I am supposing it will get it from its children height. When I'm doing so, the FlexLayout is not displayed at all. Here is a simple code:

```
<FlexLayout Direction="Column">
    <Button Text="Test Button" />
    <!-- Here I'm trying to create FlexLayout without specifying its height -->
    <FlexLayout JustifyContent="Start" AlignItems="Start" AlignContent="Start" BackgroundColor="Blue" Direction="RowReverse" Wrap="Wrap">
        <Label Text="Test Label" HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="50"  BackgroundColor="Yellow" />
    </FlexLayout>
</FlexLayout>
```

I tried everything but nothing works unless I specify HeightRequest or FlexLayout.Basis for the (inner) FlexLayout.
Any Suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you wraping the label tag inside another flexlayout tag ?

Comment: @FabriBertani this is just a sample. there will be much more controls inside. the first flexlayout is to align controls vertically, while the second is to float the controls from right to left.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I changed the first `FlexLayout` to `StackLayout` as follows, it will work. This is so weird as I assume it should work without changing it to `StackLayout` :

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Spacing="0">
    <Button Text="Test Button" />
    <FlexLayout JustifyContent="Start" AlignItems="Start" AlignContent="Start" BackgroundColor="Blue" Direction="RowReverse" Wrap="Wrap">
        <Label Text="Test Label" HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="50"  BackgroundColor="Yellow" />
    </FlexLayout>
</StackLayout>
```